# Convert int to boolean in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity.
now this is my code for game menu:

```
public class s1sc : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool toggle2 = false;
    private bool toggle3 = false;
    private bool toggle4 = false;
    private bool toggle5 = false;
    private bool toggle6 = false;
    public int maxPlayer = 0;

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        if (toggle2 = GUILayout.Toggle (toggle2, "2 player")) {
            maxPlayer = 2;
        }
        if (toggle3 = GUILayout.Toggle (toggle3, "3 player")) {
            maxPlayer = 3;
        }
        if (toggle4 = GUILayout.Toggle (toggle4, "4 player")) {
            maxPlayer = 4;
        }
        if (toggle5 = GUILayout.Toggle (toggle5, "5 player")) {
            maxPlayer = 5;
        }
        if (toggle6 = GUILayout.Toggle (toggle6, "6 player")) {
            maxPlayer = 6;
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button ("mod friendly fire", GUILayout.Width (300), GUILayout.Height (50))) {

            if (maxPlayer = 0) {
                GUILayout.TextField ("select max players!", GUILayout.Width (300), GUILayout.Height (50));
            } else {
                Application.LoadLevel ("s2"); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and i get this error when i try to run it:

> Assets/Scene 1/s1sc.cs(41,25): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert
>   type `int' to`bool'

how can i convert bool to int in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to. you have the comparison in your if-statement wrong.

It currently tries to assign the result of `GUILayout.Toggle (toggle2, "2 player")` to `toggle2`, which is a boolean.

Boolean comparison works with a double `equals` sign : like this : `==`

Keep in mind that even if you use a double equals sign, you are still trying to compare an integer to a boolean. you might try [casting or converting the integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) so you can properly compare it, but ultimately you might be better off using the same types in your comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You are using assignment operator `=`, you need to use comparison operator `==`

```
 if (toggle2 == GUILayout.Toggle (toggle2, "2 player")) 
    {
            maxPlayer = 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all an important thing to remember that C# is strict boolean language 
unlike C++ i.e

```
    if(boolean_expression)
    {
       **/*boolean expression should result into either "true" or "false" otherwise 
          you'll get compile time error */**
    }
```

therefor if you use

if(maxplayer=0)

"maxplayer=0" will result into 0 not true or false which c# language seek, if you use this expression in C++ you will not get any compilation error and 0 stands for false in C++ and "any" other value(like 1,1.1,"string",-1) other than zero will be consider as true.

**So use == which means "Equal to" not = which is an assignment operator.**

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Convert
{
    public static bool intToBool (int Number)
    {
        return (Number == 0 ? false : true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please follow SO [answer rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering)